# Multiple Web Apps (Silverlight and ASP.NET MVC) on One Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, web-deployment, language-interoperability

We are asked to add a module for a previously-developed main project. They want the new module to be written in **ASP.NET MVC**, however, the main project has been written using **Silverlight**. The two projects are completely separated (from UI to database and so on). The new module opens if the user clicks on its link provided in the page of the main project. It can be whether on a subdomain or just can follow a folder-based approach. Now my concern is on this issue that will we face any difficulties having them on one server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no issues having two separate projects released to the same web server as web servers are designed to host multiple web applications.
The only risk is that if one application has performance issues that impact on the web server which then impacts the other web application.  This risk can be mitigated against by using different application pools for the two applications.